# Spring - is using new a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, new-operator

Is creating objects *by hand*, i.e. using `new` operator instead of registering `Spring` bean and using dependency injection considered bad practice? I mean, does `Spring IoC` container have to know about all objects in the application? If so, why?

Comment: You may create objects with `new` of course. But in this case Spring will not inject any dependencies into those objects because Spring IoC will not know that object was created.

Comment: Take, for example, POJOs. Spring does not need to know about them. In fact, following uncle Bob's advice, your business logic (and thus, your POJOs) should have no knowledge that Spring is used ("keep the framework at an arm's length"). If we speak about REST endpoints, controllers,... those should be wired through DI.

Comment: @Turing85, in Spring actually almost all objects are POJOs

Comment: that is not correct. Spring heavily relies on annotations to detect and configure beans. POJO by definition are devoid of any signs of framework on the code

Comment: It depends on the object. Dependency injection is good for heavy objects, but if it is a small object, its not worth the effort, just use new keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You want Spring to create beans** for classes that :

- you want/need to inject instance(s) in other beans
- you need to inject beans (or dependencies) in their own instances.
- you want them to benefit from Spring features (instantiation management, transaction management, proxy classes Spring empowered such as Repository/Interceptor and so for...)

Services,  controllers or interceptors are example of them.
For example a controller may need inject a service or an interceptor.
As well as you don't want to handle the instantiation of these classes by implementing yourself the singleton pattern for each one. Which could be error-prone and  require boiler plate code.
So you want all of these classes to be beans managed by Spring.

**But you don't want to Spring create beans** for classes that :

- you don't want/need to inject  instance(s) in other beans
- you don't need to inject beans (or rdependencies) in their own instances
- you don't need them benefit from Spring features

Entity, DTO, Value Object are example of them.

For example an entity never needs to be injected into another entity or in a service as a dependency because entities are not created at the container startup but are generally created inside a method and have a scope limited to the methods lifespan.
As well as you don't need Spring to create instances which the lifespan is a method. The `new` operator does very well the job.
So defining them as bean instances makes no sense and appears even counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Using new is not bad and you are just giving the IoC container the responsibility of using new under the hood. IoC will know about all the classes that you register with it. When using frameworks, it's even more important to think about the applications architecture, because a framework makes bad design as easy to implement as good design.

If you don't need multiple implementations of a class, then use new.

If you think it's plausible that you may need to switch between implementations, consider your app design and find a suitable injection point so that refactoring won't be such a drain.

If you need multiple implementation of a class, then use a design pattern like a factory or a DI framework.

Not every nook and cranny of an application needs to be highly configurable. That's what leads to over-engineered and hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring implements the Dependency Injection pattern. You should inject in the container of spring the beans that are going to be used in other classes as dependence to be able to work. Usually classes that implement interfaces are injected so that if you change the implementation, the classes that use that interface do not know about the change.

I recommend you read the [post](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) about the dependency injection of Martin Fowler.